# HTML5 Video Autoplay em navegadores mobile

Tags: javascript, html5, vídeo

O Atributo autoplay na tag `VIDEO` parece não funcionar em navegadores mobile, pesquisei e parece que isso lhe diz respeito a uma politica de permissões entre o navegador e o usuário final, tentei forçar o autoplay disparando um o evento de click para um botão de play, funciona no navegador desktop mas não no mobile.

A alguma maneira de burlar isso? e configurar o autoplay para tocar nos mobiles.

Comment: Você não considera utilizar players?

Comment: O vídeo deve auto executar assim que o usuário entrar na pagina , não preciso de controles, só preciso que o vídeo auto execute.

Comment: Sim, mas o youtube dá autoplay, ele é um player não html5...entende? Vc pode usar players e esconder os controles.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como dar autoplay no video em versão mobile chrome](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257720/como-dar-autoplay-no-video-em-vers%c3%a3o-mobile-chrome)

Comment: @AnthraxisBR minha pergunta foi feita primeiro a outra pergunta que deve ser sinalizada como duplicata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível dar autoplay em um vídeo em navegadores mobile. Esta é uma limitação imposta por eles.

Esta limitação tem o intuito de se impedir o download não solicitado através da pacote de dados do usuário, economizando assim a franquia dele.

Pelo que eu saiba não existe nenhuma forma de se burlar esta limitação, apenas um evento iniciado pelo usuário, como um toque na tela pode iniciar o vídeo, e isso não pode ser simulador por javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Se o vídeo estiver em um banner na página, você pode tentar colocá-lo na segunda transição, ou seja forçar o usuário a clicar no próximo banner para poder ver o vídeo, assim, será uma requisição do próprio usuário.

Answer (score -3):

Utilize os atributos autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" autobuffer=""