# Como dar autoplay no video em versão mobile chrome

Tags: html5

Estou tentando iniciar o video em autoplay na versão mobile no celular teste no firefox e funcionou no chrome não, segue o código da tag video que estou usando

```
<video class="video" autoplay muted loop >
```

se alguém tiver alguma ideia agradeço

Comment: tentou colocar autoplay="true"?

Comment: já tentei não deu certo

Comment: Tenta utilizar javascript para iniciar o vídeo, Ex: document.getElementById("myVideo").autoplay; você pode tentar utilizar essa função no onload da página.

Comment: sim tentei fazer também esse do chrome esta tenso

Comment: É android ou iOS?

Comment: é para android.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [HTML5 Video Autoplay em navegadores mobile](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73448/html5-video-autoplay-em-navegadores-mobile)

Answer (score 2):

Os navegadores tem sua política de *auto-executar* conteúdo com a tag `<video>` usando mobile. O iOS, por exemplo, não permite `autoplay` ([veja aqui documentação oficial da Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)).

Em relação ao Android, o Firefox aceita o `autoplay`, tranquilo. Já o Chrome, só irá *auto-executar* o vídeo se ele tiver os dois atributos `autoplay muted` (`muted` significa *sem áudio*) **e** se nas configurações do navegador a **Economia de dados** estiver desativada **e** se em "*Configurações > Configurações do site > Mídia*" estiver habilitada a opção "Reprodução automática".

Creio que no caso do iOS (que não permite) e no caso do Chrome (permite dentro dos critérios acima), seja para evitar consumo de dados de rede de celular sem uma ação prévia do usuário.

Comment: pensando nisso fiz assim, "não sei se é a maneira correta"

Comment: var video = document.getElementById("video");  
            video.load();
            $(window).click(function (){
                video.play();
            });

Comment: @JulianoSouza Só adiantaria fazer qualquer coisa com gesto do usuário se a Economia de dados estiver desabilitada.

Comment: @JulianoSouza Vou precisar sair agora, mas mais tarde eu vou dar mais uma pesquisada mais aprofundada no assunto e se eu tiver novidades eu te aviso.